# How to dynamically load an off domain script that loads another script from the same domain

Tags: javascript, browser

So the situation I am in involves loading a third party script with this code:

```
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.src = 'http://someotherDomain.com/foo.js';
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';

document.body.appendChild(newScript);
```

foo.js contains the code:

```
document.write (unescape("%3Cscript src='http://someotherDomain.com/bar.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
```

The issue is that the first code snippet will execute successfully and pull in foo.js, but after foo.js is fetched the contents are not executed. I thought that after a browser loads a new script it will parse and then run the containing code. This works if I put in foo.js on initial page load, but not afterwards. Am I missing something?

Comment: `document.write` doesn't work after page load... Your first code block shows how to add scripts to the page - if you can, just use that method to load the second script from within the first script.

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense. I unfortunately do not have the ability to modify 'foo.js' right now. Looks like having it load on page load for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by Sime Vidas in the comments:

> `document.write` doesn't work after page load... Your first code block shows how to add scripts to the page - if you can, just use that method to load the second script from within the first script.